# Google security. Thunderbird risk

Tags: gnome, thunderbird, google

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and recently received a warning from Google that:

> Some apps & devices use less secure sign-in technology, which could
>   make your account vulnerable. Google recommends turning off access to
>   these apps.

So I clicked on the button to turn off access to these apps. The Google designated low risk apps (see below) I left with access were Gnome, Chrome and Thunderbird.

> 3 apps with low-risk access to your data It's safe to keep giving
>   these apps or services access if you trust and use them. They have
>   low-risk account access or Google verified their developers'
>   information.

When I came to use Thunderbird it couldn't read the mails from my Googlemail account.

So I went back to the Google security page and switched the access to less secure apps back off. Now everything works again but Google keep telling me my account is less secure.

Edit: I did as DK Bose suggested and it seems that the issue is only with Thunderbird. If access to unsecure apps is turned off, Thunderbird cannot access Googlemail. I have seen that this might be because Thunderbird should access Googlemail with "OAuth2" authentification. I don't know how to change the authentification type in Thunderbird but will find out and post the solution here when I do. Until then if someone else knows how please feel free to post the solution.

Comment: I'm confused. Where does Ubuntu come up in this, besides Gnome? Was Gnome Calendar affected when you switched off "less secure" access? Also AFAIK, Thunderbird supports high security (OAUTH 2, I think), so it doesn't require "less secure" access.

Comment: Is this a typo? *"switched the access to less secure apps back **off**. "*  That should be "on", no?

Comment: Please turn the access to less secure apps back on and then, when Google prompts you, take abundant screenshots to record what exactly Google says re. "I remember that Ubuntu was mentioned in the resulting process.". As such your question is incomplete and hence unclear.

Comment: I did as you suggested and it seems that the issue is only with Thunderbird. If access to unsecure apps is turned off, Thunderbird cannot access Googlemail. I have seen that this might be because Thunderbird should access Googlemail with "OAuth2" authentification. I don't know how to change the authentification type in Thunderbird but will find out and post the solution here when I do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was actually only between Thunderbird and Gmail, sorry for my initial mistaken belief it was to do with Ubuntu.

After changing the authentification method to OAuth2 in both the IMAP and SMTP servers Thunderbird appeared in the Google "Apps with access to your account". I then switched off "Allow less secure apps" and rebooted my machine. I then sent myself a message and it worked.

Comment: You shouldn't need to reboot anything for that to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set up 2FA for your Google account, you can create a one-off password that can only be used with a selected app. Have you tried this for Thunderbird? You can set a second one for Gnome too.